# Show object fields

Tags: php, configuration, xdebug, configure

I use xdebug php debugger.
For example

```
$date = new DateTime();
var_dump($date);
```

The output is

```
object(DateTime)[3]
```

How to XDebug to show the fields of the object?

current configuration

```
xdebug.default_enable = 1
xdebug.var_display_max_depth = 5
xdebug.show_local_vars = On
xdebug.show_exception_trace = On
xdebug.dump.SERVER = HTTP_HOST, SERVER_NAME
xdebug.dump_globals = Off
xdebug.collect_params = 4
xdebug.show_exception_trace = 1
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_host = localhost
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
xdebug.auto_trace = 1
xdebug.collect_params = 10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var_dump(get_object_vars($date));
var_dump(get_class_methods($date));
```

Comment: array
  empty
 output of var_dump(get_object_vars($date));

Comment: weird, works fine on mine, gives me 3 properties of the DateTime object

Comment: Oh. I see 'date.php'. DateTime has no fields, or they are hidden.